# How to allocate controller in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I made controller by `mix phx.gen.html`. The default location of controller generated is `lib/xxx_web/controller`.

I would like to change path `https://localhost:4000/members` to `https://localhost:4000/admin/members`.

How should I type path location, when I generate controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some option `-web Admin` in `phx.gen.html`.

```
mix phx.gen.html Context Shop shops shop_name:string address:string -web Admin
```

Answer (score 2):

Where the file is located physically on the file system means literally nothing to [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) compiler.

You need to change your `router.ex` file in order to change routing.

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand on Aleksei's comment you can either create a scoped route for actions within that controller, or, by just configuring the route to be available at that path e.g.

`get "/admin/members", MyController, :members`